# memory handling with URL.createObjectURL()

Tags: javascript

The links to the imageserver are protected that's why I need to use fetch with a authorization header and create a local duplicate with `URL.createObjectURL()`. To prevent data leaks I need to delete the object from memory  with`URL.revokeObjectURL()`. Can I do that right after the image is loaded and is there a way to reload the `<img>` to unload the memory?

Comment: "reload the <img> to unload the memory" what does that mean exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you revoke it after the image loads?

> Yes. Please use this code:

```js
img.addEventListener("load"), () => URL.revokeObjectURL(blobSrc), { once: true })
```

after revoke can you reload the image?

> No. There is no way you have to create a new url object

Comment: Seems like you inverted what should go in the quote block.